# Modal: order of operations mirroring error with multiple modals

Tags: modal-dialog, simplemodal

I have two different modals on the same page. they are each suppose to be separate modals with different content for the user to click on.

the problem is the top ends up mirroring the content of the bottom despite the difference in IDs.

Is there a method to override the order of operations? ...or is there specific JS that will differentiate the two from each other?

**here is the quick version to see the problem:** https://jsfiddle.net/anemnafair/Locnupay/2/

HTML

```
<body>
  <button id="btn1"><img src="#" alt="image1"></button>

  <div id="modal1" class="modal">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close"></span>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Second modal HTML

```
<button id="btn2"><img src="#" alt="image2"></button>

<div id="modal2" class="modal">

 <div class="modal-content">
   <span class="close"></span>

       <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
   var modal = document.getElementById('modal1');
   var btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

   btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
   span.onclick = function() {
     modal.style.display = "none";
  }
   window.onclick = function(event) {
     if (event.target == modal) {
       modal.style.display = "none";
   }
 }
```

Second Modal JS

```
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal2');
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn2");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I got most of the code from W3- http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp
Not sure if that helps any.

I need to get each modal acting separately instead of mimicking the other. That is the problem I have run out of clues of where to go next? I just need suggestions.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Morales Batovski, does this look better?